# Minus 1 in datetime during execution of loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a method to get the `datetime()` name `getdate` and this is the query for getting the date: `"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') AS serverdt;"`;

and I have 365 database just like `test01012015 || 01 for month || 01 for day || 2015` for year it is a daily database

If I already get the return value for my `getdate()` method
how to minus 1 the date every execution of loop?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate

Comment: I didnt get your question: if i already get the return value for my getdate method how to minus 1 the date every execution of loop?

Comment: DateTime.AddDays(-1) ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what about this query? `select date_add(now(),INTERVAL -1 DAY);`

Answer (score 0):

Without more info....

31 Dec backwards to 1 Jan:

```
declare @DBDate datetime
set @DBDate = '31 dec 1900'
while @DBDate >= '1 jan 1900'
begin

    --Use Date in Something
    select @DBDate

    --Increment
    select @DBDate = @DBDate - 1

End
```

Current Date back 365 days:

```
declare @DBDate datetime
set @DBDate = getdate()
while @DBDate >= getdate()-365
begin

    --Use Date in Something
    select @DBDate

    --Increment
    select @DBDate = @DBDate - 1

End
```

Now with your variable:

```
declare @DBDate datetime
set @DBDate = getdate()
while @DBDate >= getdate()-365
begin

    --Use Date in Something
    select 
        'TEST' 
        + CONVERT(varchar(20), @DBDate, 12) 
        + replace(CONVERT(varchar(20), @DBDate, 108),':', '')

    --Increment
    select @DBDate = @DBDate - 1


End
```